# Is it possible to filter attribute of dos command output?

Tags: command-line, batch, ms-dos

Below is output of this command *netsh interface ipv4 show interface*

Idx      Met     MTU                State                          Name

---

1          50      4294967295  connected   Loopback Pseudo-Interface1 
12              20               1500                 connected      Local Area Connection

But I want output to be

**Idx                     Name

  1      Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1 

 13    Local Area Connection**

Alright I know we can filter line using find or findstr:

Example:
*C:\Users\Unknown>netsh interface ipv4 show interface | find "Local"* 

 **12          20        1500  connected     Local Area Connection**

If you have any idea how to solve this problem. Please share. I will be thankful if you provide screenshot. Just giving command can also helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "tokens=1,4*" %a in ('netsh interface ipv4 show interface') do @echo %a %c
```